# Setting Pagination dynamically in Interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have a page item with name as `P1_ITEM`. It has list of countries and 'All' value(displays all countries records in IG) .

If the Item value is 'All' I need to  refresh my Interactive grid with Pagination type as 'Page' else if any one of the country is selected then I need to refresh my Interactive grid with Pagination type to 'Scroll'. Can any one help me to set pagination dynamically for Interactive Grid.

Regards,

SwaZ.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation for the pagination settings relevant to the grid widget:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/grid.html#pagination

Here's an example of setting the `scroll` property of the pagination settings for a given region (you can pass in more properties at the same time):

```
apex.region('emps').call('getViews').grid.view$.grid("option", "pagination", {scroll: false} );
```

Here's a tweet series where I break down some of the code you're seeing there: https://twitter.com/dmcghan/status/1199420591960469505